# How to get JSON data (body application/json) from a GET Request?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, postman

How can I get the json data from a GET request to a Django Rest route. I am making a GET request to a url and have data in the body of Postman as JSON(application/json). How do I get the data from this request in Django Rest Framework, in my view.

My view sends back data based on what is passed in the JSON data.

I do not want to put the data in the url as a query_param. I will be sending a lot of parameters in the JSON data body, so concatenating to the url is not what I want.

Comment: Don't send JSON in a GET request.  That should be a POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to send json format with get request you have to use post request to send data else use query param with get request.
For more info see this [django request and response tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/)